# How to add Obj-C Libs(with .h files) to swift in Flutter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, flutter

I would like to ask how to add files / Libraries of Obj-C(for example: xxxx.a + xxx.h) to swift in flutter? I'm confuse where to put the import and how to import it, try to used `linked libraries` I tried to put 1 folder inside the linked libraries,

this is my libs folder which I want to put inside project

[image]

this is from my build phases --> Link Binary with Phases

[image]

this is sample picture from runner

[image]

but when I tried to import it in Runner-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "LibHealthCombineSDK.h"
```

it's give me error `'LibHealthCombineSDK.h' file not found`

is my ways to put this libs is correct? if yes, how to used it inside swift?

Comment: Have you set a proper Bridging path in the build setting?

Comment: yes, I used the default of flutter `Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: did you get it to work? I'm facing the same problem , any help please